# Setting an event handler on a linkbutton inside a class Appointment Template won't fire

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, telerik

I have a telerik RadScheduler control which I am creating a custom appointment template for. The template binds succesfully, however sat inside my template is a linkbutton which I want to bind an event to. I can see that the event binds, however it does not call the code and hit the response.redirect, instead the page refreshes and the appointment templates dissapear. How do I get the event to handle correctly on the button click? The apptemplate is being appended on the page load.

```
public class AppTemplate : ITemplate
        {
            public void InstantiateIn(Control container)
            {
                SchedulerAppointmentContainer aptCont = (SchedulerAppointmentContainer)container;
                Appointment app = aptCont.Appointment;
            LinkButton lbs = new LinkButton();
            lbs.ID = "btnConductAppointment";
            lbs.Text = "<div style=\"font-weight:bold;\">" + app.Attributes["ApptClientID"] + "</div><div>" + app.Attributes["Title"] + " " + app.Attributes["Surname"] + "</div>";



            //nlbs.Click += btnConductAppointment_Click;
            lbs.DataBinding += new EventHandler(label1_DataBinding);
            lbs.CausesValidation = false;



            container.Controls.Add(lbs);
        }

        private void label1_DataBinding(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            LinkButton target = (LinkButton)sender;
            target.Click += new EventHandler(btnConductAppointment_Click);
        }

        protected  void btnConductAppointment_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect(PageDirectory.Default, true);
        }
    }
```

Comment: have try debugging that your code `target.Click += ...` actually performed ?

Comment: It's not running that code. If I stick a break point in it doesn't' get there. But the page is getting postback.

Comment: *`DataBinding` event Occurs when the server control binds to a data source.*  in your code, on which line you are expecting `label1_DataBinding` event  to be fired ?

Comment: and why aren't you trying `lbs.Click += new EventHandler(btnConductAppointment_Click);` in `InstantiateIn` method ?

Comment: So if the page is postback it won't know the event exists until the data is rebound?

Comment: All I can see in your code is you are subscribing `Click` event of link button on it's `DataBinding` event, I don't see when your code will raise this `DataBinding` event for link button (thus your breakpoint isn't being hit).

Answer (score 0):

Putting the bind in on the PageInit Means the event always exists.

```
protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
{
   RadScheduler1.AppointmentTemplate = new AppTemplate();
}
```